# How to read line by line out of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, read-text

input file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

what I have at this time:

```
filename=input("Please enter the filename or path: ")
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    filecontents=tuple(map(int, file.read().split()))

print(filecontents)
```

output: `(1,2,3,4,5)`

intended output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: you converted strings to numbers so you removed `'\n`. And you keep it in `tuple` so you get it as `(..., ...)`. You would have to use `for`-loop to display every value separatelly and then `print()` will display it in separated lines.

Comment: if you want intended output then you should read `filecontents = file.read()` - without spliting, converting to integer, and keeping in tuple. OR you have to convert integers back to strings and use `"\n".join()` to reverse `split()`